# 'expected a type' errors in Obj-C using Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm declaring three related classes for my program and getting numerous 'Expected a type' and 'Unknown type name' errors. Having looked at similar problems on StackOverflow, I thought that perhaps I was having an issue with circular dependencies, but I can't seem to resolve the errors by using `@class` forward declarations. What do I need to do to get this project to build?

BQUser.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BQQuestion.h"
#import "BQAnswer.h"

@interface BQUser : PFUser<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) NSString *userDescription;
@property (retain) PFFile *userImage;

- (BQQuestion *) addNewQuestion:(NSString *) question; //expected a type
- (BQAnswer *) addNewAnswer:(NSString *) answer toQuestion:(BQQuestion *)     question; //expected a type
- (void) likeAnswer: (BQAnswer *) answer; //expected a type

@end
```

BQQuestion.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BQUser.h"

@interface BQQuestion : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) BQUser *user; //unknown type name 'BQUser'; did you mean 'PFUser'?
@property (retain) NSString *questionText;
@property (retain) NSArray *answers;
@property int answerCount;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@end
```

BQAnswer.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BQUser.h"
#import "BQQuestion.h"

@interface BQAnswer : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

@property (retain) BQUser *user; //unknown type 'BQUser'; did you mean 'PFUser'?
@property (retain) BQQuestion *question; //unknown type name 'BQQuestion'
@property (retain) NSString *answerText;
@property int votes;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@end
```

Comment: It would **really** help if you pointed out which lines actually have the errors and posted the actual and complete error message. Otherwise it's all a guess.

Comment: OK, sorry. I'm getting "expected a type" errors in BQUser.h on lines 22, 23, and 24 (the method declarations), "unknown type" errors in BQQuestion.h on lines 10 and 16 (the lines that reference BQUser), and "unknown type" errors in BQAnswer.h on lines 10 and 11.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error messages as comments on the lines causing the errors.

Comment: The cause of your issue is the circular dependencies that you have. `BQAnswer.h` and `BQUser.h` import each other. Never do that. Get rid of the imports and use `@class` forward declarations instead. Same for `BQQuestion.h` and `BQUser.h`.

Comment: Thank you -- the errors didn't clear up automatically like they usually do, but the build succeeded!

Comment: I think the right answer came from @IanMacDonald. Building went fine, but Xcode kept showing the error arrows (although there were no errors, it happens some times).